# How we can print the numbers from 1 to 100 without using of loops and conditions

Tags: c

Basically the question i found on internet is: "How we can print the numbers from 1 to 100 without using of loops and conditions?" and in the answer, I got stuck at some lines below marked with bold. Can anyone explain me what is that? 
I think that the total code below is written in C as much i've my knowledge.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int);

void f1(int x)
{
  printf ("%d\n", x + 1);
  foo (x + 1);
}

void f2(int x)  //why we have used this fumction
{}

void (*tab[])(int) = { f1, f2 }; // what is this

void foo(int x)
{
  tab[!(x < 100)](x); // what is this
}

int main()
{
  foo(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `x < 100` a condition?

Comment: Much simpler method that satisfies the restrictions: `printf( "1 2 3 4 5 ..." );`

Comment: I heard there was a way to pound in nails without using a hammer.  Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 4):

`tab` is an array of two function pointers.

Since you're not allowed to use `if`, instead you use an array of functions, and index them using the result of the `!(x < 100)` comparison. When that's true it evaluates to `1`, so you call the function in `tab[1]`, which is `f2()`. When it's false it evaluates to `0`, so you call `tab[0]`, which is `f1`. So it effectively the same as:

```
if (x < 100) {
    f1(x);
} else {
    f2(x);
}
```

`f1(x)` prints `x+1` and then calls `foo(x+1)` recursively. `f2(x)` doesn't do anything, so the recursion ends when you get to this.

Comment: ok..i got your answer..but why is this void written void (*tab[])(int) = { f1, f2 }; // what is this

Comment: That's a declaration of an array followed by initialization of the array elements. It's like writing `int a[] = {1, 2};` but in this case the type of the array elements is function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`void (*tab[])(int) = { f1, f2 }; // what is this` would be an array of function pointers which take an int argument.

```
tab[!(x < 100)](x); // what is this
```

this means that you are accessing function 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the condition (false - 0 or true - 1)

The code seems to be a recursive call which would stop at 100

Comment: is the above code written in C++ ?

Comment: void (*tab[])(int) = { f1, f2 }; // what is this would be an array of function pointers which take an int argument. 

if this is an array of pointers..OK..i got this..but why is void written in the begining?

Comment: because it is a void function, its the same as void functionname (int a){}

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int p(int n) {
    return printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",
                  n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4, n+5, n+6, n+7, n+8, n+9, n+10);
}

int main() {
    return p(0), p(10), p(20), p(30), p(40), p(50), p(60), p(70), p(80), p(90), 0;
}
```

Or this more compact version, that prints one number at a time with a non obvious termination test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int p(int n) {
    return printf("%d\n", n++) - 4 && p(n);
}
int main() {
    return p(1);
}
```

Incidentally, one can make it even more cryptic this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return printf("%d\n", argc++) - 4 && main(argc, argv);
}
```

The 2 versions above still use tests, just not `if` statements.

Here is a variant that combines the idea from the OP's code with the above approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>

static void p(int n);
static void (*f[5])(int) = { p, p, p, p, exit };
static void p(int n) {
    f[printf("%d\n", n + 101)](n + 1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    p(-100);
}
```

function `p` takes an integer `n` and prints the value of `n + 101`, then invokes the function whose pointer is at the offset in the array `f` corresponding to the number of bytes output by `printf`, passing `n + 1` to this function.

The first call gets `-100` as an argument, hence prints `1` and a newline. `printf` returns 2, so `p` calls itself recursively with the value `-99`.

The second call prints `2`, and calls itself recursively with `-98`.

This process repeats until `printf` returns 4: the function called for `f[4]` is `exit` and since `printf` returns 4 when it first prints the number `100`, `exit` gets the value `0` and terminates the program with an exit status of `0`, which means success.

No loops, no conditions, no tests at all.

Comment: I'm curious now: what does `printf` return? You seem to be subtracting 4 from that?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura:  `printf` returns the number of bytes written to standard output. `2` for 1 digit numbers plus a newline, `3` for 2 digit numbers plus a newline and `4` for `100` and the final newline. Subtracting `4` from this yields `0`, which causes `&&` to return `0` immediately, exiting all recursive calls with a value of `0`, ultimately causing `main` to return 0, which indicates success.

Comment: wow, thanks for that! I'd never know :)

Answer (score 1):

This relies on recursion (in function `f1`) and dynamic array lookups (in function `foo`) instead of using either loops or conditionals.

```
void f2(int x)  //why we have used this fumction
{}
```

The `f2` function does nothing and is called when `x >= 100`, thus terminating the sequence when the maximum value is reached.

```
void (*tab[])(int) = { f1, f2 }; // what is this
```

That is an array initialization. `tab` is an array of pointers to functions taking an `int` parameter. The two elements of the array are pointers to functions `f1` and `f2`.

```
tab[!(x < 100)](x); // what is this
```

This does the same thing a conditional would in this scenario. This calls either the first or second function in `tab`, depending on whether `x < 100` or not.

When `x < 100`, the array subscript `!(x < 100)` equals `!true`, or `0` when converted to an `int`. `tab[0]` is the first element of the array, the function `f1`. The `f1` function prints and increments the number, then recurses by calling `foo` again, thus continuing the sequence.

When `x >= 100`, `tab[1]` is called, which is the second element of the array, `f2`. Since `f2` does nothing, the sequence ends when `x >= 100`.

Comment: "When `x >= 100`, `tab[0]` is called...". Would you mean `tab[1]`?

Comment: "This relies on recursion (in function `f2`)...". Would you mean `f1`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura: "The f2 function does nothing."

Comment: The expression `!(x < 100)` ultimately translates to negating `x < 100`, or, in other words, `x >= 100`. For any `x` less than 100, the expression evaluates to `0`. `tab[0]` is `f1`. So `f1(x)` will be called until `x` reaches 100, right?

Answer (score 0):

`f1` is responsible for printing and actually incrementing the count and relies on the bouncing back and forth to `foo`.

`tab` is an array of two functions, `f1` and `f2`. Look that, in `foo`, this array is indexed by a boolean expression that eventually translates to *execute `f1(count)` until `count` is greater than or equal to 100*.

`foo`, `tab`, `f1`, and `f2` are, therefore, just a way to support and terminate recursion.

The call stack would look like this when the program is executed:

```
main()
    foo(0)
        f1(0) -> print 1
            foo(1)
                f1(1) -> print 2
                    foo(2)
                        f1(2) -> print 3
                            ....
                            foo(99)
                                f1(99) -> print 100
                                    foo(100)
                                        f2(100) -> do nothing
  <---------------------------------------
```

Comment: "this array is indexed by a conditional expression" - `!(x < 100)` is not a conditional-expression. It's a unary-expression whose operand is a relational-expression.

Comment: @jspcal, thanks. I've just corrected the answer.